# Sync Framework Select Changes Stored Procedure - Performance/Scalability/Improvement

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, scalability, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 to synchronize a high number of concurrent end user with a central database server.

Environment:

- 1500 concurrent clients connecting to 1 central database server
- A webservice will be used as server-side SyncProvider
- There are multiple tables with more than 2.000.000 records

**Problems**
The SelectChanges SP regularly runs out of time (CommandTimeout = 60).
The reason why it is probably very slow:

- Sync Framework creates indexes on the local_update_peer_timestamp column but don't make use of it at all.

  - Even after recreating statistics the index is not used
  - Index Hints causes full index scans instead of seek operations (even if the given timestamp is way bigger than the biggest local_update_peer_timestamp value)

**Questions**
In my opinion something is going really bad. MS Sql Server 2008 R2 should be able to create proper execution plans

- How can I improve the Select Changes?

  - taking into account tables which can grow over 8.000.000 records
  - making sure SQL Server makes use of the index to built up the execution plan
- Are there other potential reasons why this query is too slow?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `CommandTimeout` property on the `SqlSyncProvider`, so if you don't care how much time it takes, you can get around this issue by setting the command timeout to exceed the amount of time the longest selectchanges query takes.

I've noticed performance issues with the selectchanges stored procedures as well. SQL seems to be slow about querying the tracking tables. I suspect at least part of this is memory pressure, since during normal operation you won't be querying the tracking tables. They will have updates/inserts, but I don't think those will cause the right parts of the right indexes to get loaded into memory. In isolated environments when no normal operations are occurring, the selectchanges procedures go much faster.

You could try adding columns to the tracking table (by adding them to the list of filter columns) and setting up custom indexes and modifying the stored procedures to use your custom indexes. I was able to get some improvement doing that, but maybe not enough to justify all the effort involved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am affraid of increasing the CommandTimeout as final solution. I did this already as temporary workaround and I want a real improvement, but still thanks for your tip. About the filtered columns. Thanks I will try to get some performance improvements by doing that. If I have some improvements I will notice you if you are curious about my solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using filter clauses then the filter criteria go in a where clause, which means that SQL server may choose to execute the where clause for each row in the select, causing serious performance issues.

What you could do in this case is create your own version of the selectchanges sproc which applies the filter criteria in a join, which will improve performance.